# replacing values in dataframe using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do a 'find and replace' in a dataframe `data` on a specific column `type1` using terms stored in a dictionary. I first make all existing values in the dataframe to be uppercase. I create the dictionary `mdata`, I make sure they are all uppercase as well. Then through the `for` syntax I loop through the items in `mdata` replacing accordingly. This code used to work before I turned it into a function.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

```
def to_fish(data, fish):
    data['type1'] = data['type1'].str.upper()
    if fish == 'monument':
        mdata = {
            'natural': 'NATURAL FEATURe',
            'DITCH TERMINUS': 'DITCH',
            'DITCH RECUT': 'DITCH',
            'NATURAL_lyr': 'NATURAL FEATURE'
        }
        mdata = {k.upper(): v.upper() for k, v in mdata.items()}

        for copa, fish in mdata.items():
            data = data.str.rstrip().str.lstrip().replace(copa, fish, regex=True)
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? It isn't returning the updated dataframe in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```py
data['type1'] = data['type1'].map(mdata)
```

Comment: before i delete my post, can I add the details into your post so there is additional info for OP to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this to get the results.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Hello','Bye','OK','Hi','Bonjour'],
                   'B':['Jack','Jill','Bryan','Kevin','Susan'],
                   'C':['High','High','Middle','Middle','Low']})
print (df)
lookup_dict = {'High':'California','Middle':'Chicago','Low':'New York'}
df['C'] = df['C'].map(lookup_dict)
print (df)
```

Before:

```
         A      B       C
0    Hello   Jack    High
1      Bye   Jill    High
2       OK  Bryan  Middle
3       Hi  Kevin  Middle
4  Bonjour  Susan     Low
```

After:

```
         A      B           C
0    Hello   Jack  California
1      Bye   Jill  California
2       OK  Bryan     Chicago
3       Hi  Kevin     Chicago
4  Bonjour  Susan    New York
```